# Unterschied zwischen "an die" und "um die"

Tags: difference

> Ihr erster Freund war ein Mann um die vierzig.
>   Da waren an die 40 Teilnehmer.

Ausgehend von diesen Beispielsätzen, kann man darauf schließen, dass "um die" in Bezug auf das Alter verwendet wird und "an die" auf die Anzahl? Oder sind beide Ausdrücke austauschbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"An die" kann für "nahezu" stehen. Die Anzahl wurde nahezu erreicht, aber nicht überschritten.

"Um die" steht für "ungefähr", die Anzahl kann also geringer oder höher sein.

Comment: Um die zweite Teilfrage zu beantworten: Beide Sätze sind auch genau umgekehrt valide: `Ihr erster Freund war ein Mann an die vierzig` (ungewöhnlich aber gültig: Man schätzt, dass er knapp unter 40 ist, aber eben noch nicht drüber). `Da waren um die 40 Teilnehmer` (es könnten also auch 43 gewesen sein)